# Preparing success rate diagram in IDRISI?

Tags: terrset

I am looking to produce 'Success Rate Curve' of my Landslide Susceptibility Zonation Map' earlier prepared in IDRISI Selva 17.0 edition.

Is there any way to produce the following diagram in the software which is required to illustrate overall accuracy of the produced product?

I have already collected the landslide locations in my study area (points) that are required for the accuracy assessment.

Is there a tool and procedure that could help me to derive the below diagram for the intended purpose?

[image: Accuracy Assessment]

Comment: @polyGeo do you have any thoughts? How would I prepare Success Rate Curve?

Comment: I am not an IDRISI user. My edits have been to try and make your question more attractive to potential answerers.